# How to ignore a message in google pubsub and do not acknolwedge it back?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-pubsub

Hi I am working with a topic and subscription where  I want to acknowledge only specific messages in one topic subscription and ignore the rest of the messages.Is there a way or process how we can ignore the messages in pubsub
is there any specific way of routing a message to specific subscription.
in Pubsub with one topic and subscription could we recive the messages based on time filter.

regards
Thank you

Comment: It's not clear. Yes you can have several subscription on PubSUb topic and add a filter to route only some message to a subscription and ignore others. But what's your issue with that? What did you try? WHat does not work as  you wish?

Comment: I am running different cloud run instances in parallel which are  stream pulling the messages from a subscription where I want to route messages based on attributes the cloudrun instances that are running in parallel.Does this behavior be developed with one topic and subscription

Comment: Again, I didn't catch you...

Answer (score 1):

In Google Cloud Pub/Sub, messages are typically delivered to all subscribers of a subscription. If you want to selectively acknowledge specific messages and ignore others within a single subscription, you'll need to implement your own message filtering and processing logic.

In your subscriber code, implement logic to filter messages based on their content or attributes. For example, you can inspect the content of each message or check its attributes, and then decide whether to acknowledge it or not.

If you want more granular control over which messages are processed, you can create multiple subscriptions for the same topic, each with its own set of filtering rules. You can then have different subscribers for each subscription, and each subscriber can be configured to process messages differently. For example, you can create one subscription for messages that need to be acknowledged and another subscription for messages that should be ignored. Then, you can have separate subscriber processes for each subscription.